# Uninstalling ArcGIS extensions from earlier version after ArcGIS upgraded?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-engine

I uninstalled ArcGIS 9.3.1 (server, desktop, engine), then installed ArcGIS10.0 (Server, Desktop, engine).

When I tried to uninstall some arcmap extensions, I got error 1001 "unable to get installer types".

In other words, I forgot to heed [this advice](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/0df20605-b457-42d6-b63c-341a3824474a.htm):

> Please note that you must uninstall
>   the custom component before you
>   attempt to uninstall ArcGIS. The
>   reason for that is that custom
>   components need to loaded at
>   install/uninstall time.

Does anyone know how to cleanly uninstall this without uninstalling 10.0 and reinstalling 9.3.1?

**Update**: I think I've cleaned things up using Revo Uninstaller, then cleaning the registry using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd second Mapperz suggestion of the Revo-Unistaller, as with the defunct COM Explorer, the freeware version will get the job done. But the Pro version gets routinely updated and while it will work in trial mode, it is such a useful tool you should probably purchase it to have available. http://www.revouninstaller.com/download-professional-version.php

If the 3rd party extensions with ArcGIS version dependencies that you are interested in removing laid down registry entries correctly you should be able to track the components manually in the registry edits.

Do a registry backup first and then start by disabling any orphaned services from the extensions.

I'd start looking the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

You want the Product Code CSLIDs listed as Product Code or in the UnistallString, and make a note of any other associated CSLIDs

If the package install was MSI based try to uninstall with the indicated msiexec /x for the Product Code's CSLID.  If the installer is intact--everything should come off cleanly.

If extension was not MSI based, see if installer executable is intact and when executed has an uninstall option and run it.

Unfortunately, if either installer is corrupted (missing components from the extension or from the ArcGIS uninstall/upgrade) you'll only achieve a partial removal and with the list of CSLIDs you'll need to chase things down manually in the registry and the file system and doing deletions as you go.

The Revo-Unistaller reliably automates most of this.

Comment: Thanks Stuart!  This is a useful tool, hard to test different situations, but I think this will work in combination with CCleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if the custom extension are deployed via just plain dll's, then you can go and unregister the particular dll's.

If the extensions are more advanced and are saving their state or version to the registry, etc, then you'll have to delete those keys.

Uninstallers like 'Revo-Unistaller' do not always work, since they look only in the standard places, and the custom extension my not be registered in these places (like the Add-Remove programs list)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Esri atricle discussing a complete uninstallation of all 9.3[.1] components:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/install_guides/arcgis_desktop_install_guide/index.html#//008700000015000000.htm

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to be just for ESRI's components.  It doesn't say how to uninstall 3rd party custom extensions that depend on a particular version of ESRI assemblies being installed.

Comment: that was my answer until I  deleted it after rereading Kirk's question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a uninstaller app:

http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html

Advanced mode adds program-specific Registry key access to the context menu.

Uses the Registry Keys to find specific keys for software (includes arcgis)

**BACKUP your registry first - (to usb recommended)**